# Error while accessing google webservice from oracle db

Tags: oracle, google-maps, oracle-apex

I was trying to accesss goggle map webservice from ORACLE PL/SQL in following way but receiving error : ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-29268: HTTP client error 403 - Forbidden

```
select httpuritype('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=30+Rockefeller+center,New+York,NY,USA&sensor=false').getclob() from dual
```

Kindly suggest

Comment: Check that your database server is able to connect to that service from the command line. e.g. if you're on linux, use `curl` to test it.

Comment: How can I check, please suggest some guidelines/url

Comment: Just use `curl` to test if you can access the URL. If it doesn't work, the problem is nothing to do with your database and you'll need to look at the network connection.

Comment: Thanks  Jeffrey .Db sever is able to connect to that service from the command line as we checked through curl command.Also We have given full ACL privileges ,Kindly suggest what can be other possible reasons?

Comment: Sorry, don't know - if the exact same URL works from the server but not from within the DB, I don't know what could cause that. It won't be the ACL because a network ACL error is an Oracle error (not a HTTP error).

Comment: When I tried to execute select UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('HTTP://MAPS.GOOGLEAPIS.COM') from dual 
It gives me output of XML with inclusion  <title>The URL you requested has been blocked</title>...Kindly suggest..

Comment: Not sure - sounds like something in your infrastructure is blocking these outgoing requests, possibly a firewall issue. In your position I would go and talk to your network administrator.